# Rows to Columns from a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a data frame like below

[image]

i tried using explode but didn't worked.
and i would like to convert to the below format
[image]

i am using the below code

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests

url ="https://url/Token"
api_url = "url/Responses?pageSize=1"
r = requests.post('url/Token', data={'userName': 'userName','password': 'password','grant_type' :'password'})
d = r.json()
t = d['access_token']
headers =  {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {t}"}
data = requests.get(api_url,headers=headers).json()
result = pd.json_normalize(data,record_path=['Data'])
df= result.explode('ResponseFields').reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('ResponseFields')))
final = df.pivot_table(index=['TicketNumber','SubmitDateTimeUtc'],columns='FormFieldKey',values='Value', aggfunc='first')



Appreciate your help.

Thanks
```

### sample Data

### {'Data': [{'Uid': '770d152d-1f07-ea11-828a-00155df8e0e9',
'UserUid': '119a203c-45f0-4901-bd2b-d347210cf250',
'FormUid': '7204be0c-1307-ea11-828a-00155df8e0e9',
'Title': 'reimbursement test - 12',
'TicketNumber': 'AD8F',
'SyncDateTimeUtc': '2019-11-14T20:41:56.043Z',
'SubmitDateTimeUtc': '2019-11-14T20:41:56.043Z',
'ResponseFields': [{'FormFieldKey': 'FIRST_NAME',
'Value': 'Chan',
'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'LAST_NAME', 'Value': 'Marlyn', 'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'EMP_', 'Value': '12', 'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'EMAIL',
'Value': 'cmarlyn945@gmail.com ',
'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'FACILITY', 'Value': 'ABC Remote south', 'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'TYPE', 'Value': 'Short call out 3', 'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'AMOUNT', 'Value': '24.00', 'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'RECEIPT_DAY_DATE', 'Value': '11/14/2019', 'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'BEG_DAY__DATE', 'Value': '11/12/2019', 'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'END_DAY_DATE', 'Value': '11/14/2019', 'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'SUBMIT_DAY_DATE', 'Value': '11/14/2019', 'Files': []},
{'FormFieldKey': 'RECEIPT_IMAGE_FILE',
'Value': '{"displayName":"1573764018026424446650638108755.jpg","systemName":"3c7e4b58-273b-4d27-92c8-f79f9be55940.jpg","url":""}',
'Files': [{'UploadedFileName': '1573764018026424446650638108755.jpg',
'Url': 'https://test.net/tpf/aa/Forms/Response462250/3c7e4b58-273b-4d27-92c8-f79f9be55940.jpg?md5=5a8e6bdd6612ff29d26016a43348e477&*tk365*=exp=1668939087~acl=%2Ftpf%2Faa%2FForms%2FResponse462250%2F3c7e4b58-273b-4d27-92c8-f79f9be55940.jpg%2A~hmac=384b663258dc19e1e5ef2b4bd71c9bd6ae5b05117e4e0f654078863cc09fd985',
'Md5': '5a8e6bdd6612ff29d26016a43348e477'}]},
{'FormFieldKey': 'SIGNATURE_CANVAS',
'Value': '[[{"x":1286,"y":536},{"x":1286,"y":656},{"x":1381,"y":394},{"x":1386,"y":376},{"x":1386,"y":369},{"x":1388,"y":362},{"x":1388,"y":357},{"x":1388,"y":353}],[{"x":304,"y":195},{"x":299,"y":191},{"x":292,"y":181},{"x":283,"y":172},{"x":274,"y":158},{"x":260,"y":144},{"x":239,"y":128},{"x":218,"y":112},{"x":202,"y":105},{"x":186,"y":105},{"x":174,"y":117},{"x":163,"y":140},{"x":151,"y":186},{"x":149,"y":239},{"x":153,"y":292},{"x":158,"y":341},{"x":163,"y":378},{"x":170,"y":403},{"x":179,"y":424},{"x":188,"y":438},{"x":202,"y":447},{"x":218,"y":447},{"x":232,"y":443},{"x":250,"y":438},{"x":269,"y":431},{"x":290,"y":427},{"x":308,"y":422},{"x":322,"y":415},{"x":334,"y":406}],[{"x":352,"y":267},{"x":352,"y":260},{"x":352,"y":258},{"x":352,"y":258},{"x":352,"y":258},{"x":357,"y":265},{"x":357,"y":281},{"x":361,"y":304},{"x":361,"y":327},{"x":361,"y":353},{"x":361,"y":373},{"x":361,"y":390},{"x":361,"y":399},{"x":361,"y":406},{"x":361,"y":399},{"x":361,"y":378},{"x":359,"y":346},{"x":352,"y":290},{"x":345,"y":244},{"x":345,"y":214},{"x":345,"y":191},{"x":345,"y":172},{"x":350,"y":161},{"x":359,"y":151},{"x":380,"y":144},{"x":403,"y":144},{"x":429,"y":144},{"x":447,"y":149},{"x":466,"y":158},{"x":479,"y":175},{"x":489,"y":195},{"x":489,"y":216},{"x":486,"y":235},{"x":477,"y":255},{"x":466,"y":272},{"x":447,"y":286},{"x":424,"y":295},{"x":398,"y":297},{"x":373,"y":297},{"x":355,"y":288}],[{"x":572,"y":163},{"x":572,"y":163},{"x":572,"y":163},{"x":567,"y":175},{"x":567,"y":198},{"x":565,"y":242},{"x":572,"y":295},{"x":579,"y":350},{"x":583,"y":394},{"x":590,"y":427},{"x":595,"y":445},{"x":595,"y":457},{"x":590,"y":457},{"x":577,"y":438},{"x":560,"y":403},{"x":537,"y":341},{"x":523,"y":290},{"x":519,"y":265},{"x":519,"y":244},{"x":521,"y":225},{"x":535,"y":212},{"x":572,"y":198},{"x":637,"y":184},{"x":692,"y":175},{"x":750,"y":163},{"x":775,"y":156},{"x":796,"y":147},{"x":810,"y":142},{"x":810,"y":135},{"x":799,"y":135},{"x":771,"y":140}],[{"x":644,"y":471},{"x":669,"y":447},{"x":688,"y":424},{"x":720,"y":392},{"x":787,"y":339},{"x":808,"y":320},{"x":824,"y":302},{"x":817,"y":295},{"x":803,"y":295},{"x":778,"y":299},{"x":752,"y":316},{"x":734,"y":341},{"x":725,"y":366},{"x":725,"y":390},{"x":736,"y":410},{"x":757,"y":424},{"x":782,"y":429},{"x":810,"y":429},{"x":842,"y":417},{"x":868,"y":394},{"x":886,"y":369},{"x":896,"y":334},{"x":891,"y":302},{"x":879,"y":279},{"x":863,"y":260},{"x":854,"y":249},{"x":849,"y":244},{"x":849,"y":244},{"x":866,"y":249},{"x":893,"y":260},{"x":967,"y":281},{"x":1044,"y":297},{"x":1129,"y":304},{"x":1206,"y":309},{"x":1245,"y":316},{"x":1270,"y":323},{"x":1293,"y":329},{"x":1300,"y":341},{"x":1293,"y":362},{"x":1256,"y":390},{"x":1164,"y":429},{"x":1060,"y":447},{"x":923,"y":452},{"x":805,"y":454},{"x":572,"y":464}]]',
'Files': []}],
'IpAddress': '111.11.11.67',
'DeviceId': None}],
'TotalRecords': 10020,
'ErrorCode': '',
'ErrorMessage': '',
'IsSuccess': True}

Above code works perfectly fine for page size =1 . When i change to
api_url = "url/Responses?pageSize=15"
i am getting the below error

[image]

Comment: Please add your starting and ending dataframes as text instead of images so that we can more easily copy and work with them. Check out this post for help on posting good reproducible pandas examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1):

you can use **pivot_table**:

```
# if ResponseFields' type is string:
#import ast
#df['ResponseFields']=df['ResponseFields'].apply(ast.literal_eval) convert string to dict

result = pd.json_normalize(data,record_path=['Data'])
df= result.explode('ResponseFields').reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('ResponseFields')))
final = df.pivot_table(index=['TicketNumber','SubmitDateTimeUtc'],columns='FormFieldKey',values='Value', aggfunc='first')

#if you want to see all columns
df['Files']=df['Files'].astype(str)
final = df.pivot_table(index=['Uid', 'UserUid', 'FormUid', 'Title', 'TicketNumber', 'Files','SyncDateTimeUtc','SubmitDateTimeUtc', 'IpAddress'],columns='FormFieldKey',values='Value', aggfunc='first')
final=final.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you. But i am getting only the First Name Not the other columns(LAST_NAME.......)  Not sure if it is something with "aggfunc"

Comment: TicketNumber      SubmitDateTimeUtc        FIRST_NAME
AD8F          2010-11-14T20:41:56.043Z Chan

Comment: please make sure you use it correctly. Because it works fine for me. You are still getting an error, write this:`print(df.to_dict())` and add the output to the question.

Comment: {'Uid': {0: '770d152d-1f07-ea11-828a-00155df8e0e9'}, 'UserUid': {0: '119a203c-45f0-4901-bd2b-d347210cf250'}, 'FormUid': {0: '7204be0c-1307-ea11-828a-00155df8e0e9'}, 'Title': {0: 'reimbursement test - 12'}, 'TicketNumber': {0: 'AD8F'}, 'SyncDateTimeUtc': {0: '2019-11-14T20:41:56.043Z'}, 'SubmitDateTimeUtc': {0: '2019-11-14T20:41:56.043Z'}, 'IpAddress': {0: '111.11.11.67'}, 'DeviceId': {0: None}, 'FormFieldKey': {0: 'FIRST_NAME'}, 'Value': {0: 'Chan'}, 'Files': {0: []}}

Comment: This is the transformed state. Try this: `print(df.head().to_dict('list'))`

Comment: Not letting me paste the data. How do i paste it?

Comment: to question or to my answer ?

Comment: Not letting me paste the answer data set because of character limit

Comment: Can you paste the whole code you used to the question?

Comment: okey i edited my answer. Can you check it ?

Comment: Copied code along with sample json data to my initial thread.

Comment: if you want to see all columns in final df check my answer.

Comment: 1 result = pd.json_normalize(data,record_path=['Data'])
      2 df= result.explode('ResponseFields').reset_index(drop=True)
----> 3 df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('ResponseFields')))
      4 final = df.pivot_table(index=['TicketNumber','SubmitDateTimeUtc'],columns='FormFieldKey',values='Value', aggfunc='first')
      AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'